# How set the Backgound Text using javascript or JQuery in the input text field or text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I hardly know any Jquery or Javascript. So, I beg your pardon in advance if I ask any question very stupidly.

I want to set backgound text for two text fields. 
My two text fields are

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" backgroundText="First Name" runat="server" Width="80px"  Style="float: left;"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLName"  backgrountText="Last Name"
                                    Width="110px" Style="float: left"></asp:TextBox>
```

One of friend wrote the jquery for the first text box and it is working perfectly. 
this code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var inpName = $('#txtFName');
        var backgroundText = inpName.attr('backgroundText');

        inpName.val(backgroundText);

        inpName.focus(function(){
            if(inpName.val() == backgroundText) inpName.val('');
        }).blur(function(){
            if(inpName.val() == '') inpName.val(backgroundText);
        });


    });
```

But if I use this code for the last-name text box, then it does not work
what I did, I copied the entire Jquery code and just replace the `var inpName = $('#txtFName');` as `var inpName = $('#txtLName');`
But, If I do so, My first working text box (txtFirst) does work properly.
but, If I write like this way:
$(document).ready(function(){
            checkRequiredInputs();

```
        var inpName = $('#txtFName');
        var backgroundText = inpName.attr('backgroundText');

        inpName.val(backgroundText);

        inpName.focus(function(){
            if(inpName.val() == backgroundText) inpName.val('');
        }).blur(function(){
            if(inpName.val() == '') inpName.val(backgroundText);
        });

        var inpName = $('#txtLName');
        var backgroundText = inpName.attr('backgroundText');

        inpName.val(backgroundText);

        inpName.focus(function(){
            if(inpName.val() == backgroundText) inpName.val('');
        }).blur(function(){
            if(inpName.val() == '') inpName.val(backgroundText);
        });
```

I does not work anymore, Why?
Can Anyone Explain me Why is this happening? and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: In ASP.NET the `ID` attribute is a server-side ID, and the client side (HTML) `id` attribute that is rendered is often different.  Are you able to verify that the rendered `id` attribute is indeed 'txtLName'?

Comment: Coding Gorilla, the Code I have Pasted here is working perfectly as I told you earlier and I also told you I don do Javascript or or jquery usually. My freind looks into those matters. But since he is unavailable, so I have to look into this.One more thing, wait bit, I am editing my post.

Comment: This may not be a javascript/jquery at all, it may simply be that your `$('#txtFName')` needs to be changed.  Can you tell me what version of ASP.NET you're using?

Comment: I am using asp .net 3.0, but IF it is not a jquey then why is it working if I don do any edit.

Comment: That's the curious part, with asp.net 3.0, the client id should not be the same as the server side id.  Is your javascript inside your .aspx page or is it in a separate .js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my own question and later I have solve it using ajaxWaterMarkExtender. Here I am pasting the code (modified) that is working for me perfectly. This is the code in aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" backgroundText="First Name" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxForUI"
                            Width="80px" Style="float: left;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtFName_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server"
                            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtFName" WatermarkCssClass="waterMark" WatermarkText="First Name">
                        </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLName" CssClass="textBoxForUI" backgrountText="Last Name"
                            Width="110px" Style="float: left"></asp:TextBox>
                        <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtLName_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server"
                            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtLName" WatermarkCssClass="waterMark" WatermarkText="Last Name">
                        </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shameless self promotion:

I created a plugin to do just this but it uses the HTML5 placeholder attribute.

http://designindevelopment.com/plugins/replaceholder-jquery-plugin/

See if it does what you are looking for, if not I can help tweak what you have.

Comment: I cantnot use HTML 5, (according to the team decision), so I have to solve it without using the HTML 5, I am looking for your Tweak. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some jQuery Watermark plugins.

This one here is not bad http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your javascript as follows:

```
    var inpName = $('#<%=txtFName.ClientID %>');
    var backgroundText = inpName.attr('backgroundText');

    inpName.val(backgroundText);

    inpName.focus(function(){
        if(inpName.val() == backgroundText) inpName.val('');
    }).blur(function(){
        if(inpName.val() == '') inpName.val(backgroundText);
    });

    var inpName = $('#<%=txtLName.ClientID %>');
    var backgroundText = inpName.attr('backgroundText');

    inpName.val(backgroundText);

    inpName.focus(function(){
        if(inpName.val() == backgroundText) inpName.val('');
    }).blur(function(){
        if(inpName.val() == '') inpName.val(backgroundText);
    });
```

This puts the id that will be rendered to the client into your javascript, as it usually does not match the server side ID attribute.

Comment: I have tried it, but it is giving me the error: "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 
" what does this mean?